# Why does my while loop at the bottom run once?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, caesar-cipher

[Caesar Cipher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPz0s.png)

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def caesar(text, shift, direction):
  cipher_text = ""
  for letter in text:
    text_position = alphabet.index(letter)
    if direction == "encode":
      new_text_position = text_position + shift
    elif direction == "decode":
     new_text_position = text_position - shift
    else:
      print("Error, invalid entry.")
    cipher_text += alphabet[new_text_position]
  print(f"Your cipher text is {cipher_text}")

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
while direction != "encode" or direction != "decode":
  direction = input("Invalid entry. Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
  if direction == "encode" or direction == "decode":
    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
    caesar(text, shift, direction)
```

This is a Caesar Cipher program from Angela Yu's Udemy course on Python. The idea at the bottom is simply to allow the user to progress as long as the input is 'encode' or 'decode'. As you can see, the while loop runs once even if the input is a valid answer. It should just skip right to the 'if' statement.

I tried to change the logic of the 'direction' variable from 'or' to 'and' as per someone's suggestion on the technology board on 4chan, but that doesn't work because it only accepts one input. So then I tried changing the while to an if, which works, but doesn't allow the user to repeat in the event that the input is not one of the two options. I also tried to move the if statement out of the domain of the while loop, but that just causes the program to run the while loop even if the correct answer is inputted.

Comment: We couldn't possibly help without seeing your code. We're good, but we're not mind readers

Comment: I know, I was trying to find a way to post the screenshot but it wouldn't let me. It should show now if you refresh. Sorry.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, bring through relevant code form the udemy link as well as your attempts. Links die, and Stackoverflow is meant to live for a long time and provide help to other folks struggling with similar problems. Also please don't post the code as a screenshot. Copy/paste and then highlight and click the '{}' button on the editor to preserve line feed and white space. Sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: I didn’t actually downvote, but pleased read http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, data or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

[Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Just did that there. It should show as formatted code now.
Sorry, first time posting here.

Comment: It should run forever. `direction` can't be both `"encode"` *and* `"decode"`. You want `and`, not `or`. The body of the `if` statement should then be *after* the loop, with no need for the `if` statement itself.

Comment: So, I figured it out. It turns out the answer actually is 'and' instead of 'or'. The first time I tried it, I must have had bad indentation somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: It is better to attach your code directly instead of uploading a screenshot, so that anyone interested in answering can run/debug it.**

The logic error is caused by 2 mistakes.

**Firstly**, the condition for that `while` loop is such that it will always be `True` because:

1. If you enter "encode": `direction != "encode"` will be `False` but `direction != "decode"` will be `True` and hence the `or` condition will be `True`.
2. If you enter "decode": `direction != "decode"` will be `False` but `direction != "encode"` will be `True` and hence the `or` condition will be `True`.

Therefore, you must use the `and` operator so that the loop is executed only if `direction` is not equal to **both** "encode" `and` "decode".

**Secondly**, even if you replace `or` with `and`, the error will persist because you placed the last `if` statement **within** that while loop by keeping the same level of indent. This means that the `if` statement will only be executed **if** the while loop is entered. Otherwise, the interpreter will go over the whole `while` loop, which includes the `if` statement. Therefore you have to un-indent that `if` statement so that it is separate from that `while` loop.

It should look like this:

```
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
while direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
    direction = input("Invalid entry. Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")

if direction == "encode" or direction == "decode":
    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
    caesar(text, shift, direction)
```

Also, the while loop looks better/more pythonic like this:

```
while True:
direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
if direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
    print("Invalid input. ", end="")
    continue
else:
    break
```

The loop is infinite by default, because the actual condition is replaced with `True` and will remain so forever, which means that I will have to do something else to "break" out of the loop as there is no condition for the `while` loop to check for. If, after taking user input, the `direction` is anything other than "encode" or "decode", it prints `"Invalid input. "` and the `end=""` argument specifies what to "end" the string with. It is `end=\n` by default which is why you always get a newline with a `print` function. So now, the following `print` function's string is printed right next to this string as they are on the same line. If the conditions are met, however, it follows the `else` clause and "breaks" out of the loop.

**Finally**, that last `if` statement is unnecessary because the `while` loop is going to take care of the input validation. Your final code should look something like this:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def caesar(text, shift, direction):
    cipher_text = ""
    for letter in text:
        text_position = alphabet.index(letter)
        if direction == "encode":
            new_text_position = text_position + shift
        elif direction == "decode":
            new_text_position = text_position - shift
        else:
            print("Error, invalid entry")
        cipher_text += alphabet[new_text_position]
    print(f"Your cipher text is {cipher_text}")


while True:
    direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
    if direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
        print("Invalid input. ", end="")
        continue
    else:
        break


if direction == "encode" or direction == "decode":
    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
    caesar(text, shift, direction)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using OR operator instead of AND in the while loop
2. The if statement that is inside the while loop should be out

Here's a fixed code:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
            'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
            's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a',
            'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
            'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
            't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def caesar(text: str, shift: int, direction: str) -> str:
    cipher = ""
    for letter in text:
        if letter not in alphabet:
            cipher += letter
            continue
        pos = alphabet.index(letter)
        new = pos + shift if direction == "encode" else pos - shift
        cipher += alphabet[new]
    return cipher

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt: ")
while direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
  direction = input("Invalid entry. Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt: ")
text = input("Type your message: ").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number: "))
print(caesar(text, shift, direction))
```

1. The operator in the while loop should be AND not OR

Here's an example, assume that the user typed "encode".

using OR operator:

```
while direction != "encode" or direction != "decode":
```

the while loop will run only if AT LEAST 1 of the conditions is True

is "encode" != "encode"? False

is "encode" != "decode"? True

even though it's a valid answer, the loop still runs because the second condition is True

using AND operator:

```
while direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
```

the while loop will only run if BOTH parameters are true

is "encode" != "encode"? False

is "encode" != "decode"? True

In this case the while loop would only run if the answer is neither equal to "encode" and "decode"

2. The if statement is unnecessary

```
while direction != "encode" or direction != "decode":
  direction = input("Invalid entry. Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
  if direction == "encode" or direction == "decode":
    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
    caesar(text, shift, direction)
```

The if statement is inside the while loop, so if the user type a valid answer in the first try, the while loop won't run and the content inside the if statement also not, so the if statement need to be outside of the while loop

But if the code is out of the while loop, that means that the user already typed a correct answer, there's no need to check it again, so you can remove just remove it

```
while direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
  direction = input("Invalid entry. Type 'encode' to encrypt, or 'decode' to decrypt: ")
text = input("Type your message: ").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number: "))
print(caesar(text, shift, direction))
```